# Must supply a value for form control at index

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I use reactive forms, and on `ngInit` i set data to fieldsngOnInit() {

```
this.questionControls.controls["inputTitle"].setValue("text"),
        this.questionControls.controls["inputPlaceHolder"].setValue("text"),
        this.questionControls.controls["selectBoxOptions"].setValue(
            this.formBuilder.array(this.getOptionsAsFormGroups())
        ),  --> here i get error
        this.questionControls.controls["selectBoxTitle"].setValue("text"),
        this.questionControls.controls["checkBoxTitle"].setValue("text"),
        this.questionControls.controls["radioBtnTitle"].setValue("text");
}
```

But I get error

> ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control at index: 0.

Here is method for options

```
this.selectedQuestion.options = ['a', 'b', 'c']
private getOptionsAsFormGroups(): FormGroup[] {
        let inputs: FormGroup[] = [];
        if (this.selectedQuestion.options) {

            for (let v of this.selectedQuestion.options)
                inputs.push(
                    this.formBuilder.group({
                        value: [v]
                    })
                );
        } else {
            inputs.push(this.getEmptyForm());
        }
        return inputs;
    }
```

and here is html

```
                    <tr *ngFor="let options of selectOptionsFormGroup.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <input formControlName="value" type="text" matInput placeholder="option" />
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: As the error says, what happens if you “supply a value” attribute to your input element?

Comment: If you mean like this `<input formControlName="value" type="text" value="options" matInput placeholder="option" />` ...??? I get the sam error

Comment: Feels like having some sub form(s) might help you. If that's the case check https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form